# Can Chosen weapons be upgraded with "Modular Weapon Breakthrough"?

Tags: xcom-2, xcom-2-war-of-the-chosen

When you get the opportunity through Resistance Covert Missions to have a "Breakthrough: Modular xx research" (which adds an additional upgrade slot to all weapons of that category), does it also add more slots to the Chosen weapons?

Answer (score 2):

No, it does not give additional upgrade slots to the Chosen weapons (I verified this in game by doing the breakthrough and then attempting to upgrade, but it still says "Current primary weapon cannot be upgraded")